# Disable "hidden conversations" in GitHub pull requests?

Tags: github

When I go to a page of an open PR in GitHub, e.g. `https://github.com/xyz/abc/pull/123`, when the number of conversations exceeds some limit, GitHub automatically collapses some of them in the middle under a box that says "[n] hidden conversations"; you have to click "Load more" in order to see them.

Since the open conversations are the most important thing on a PR and the reason I open or refresh the page in the first place, is there a way to undo this and always show all the conversations?  I haven't seen anything relevant in settings; does a browser extension exist to do this?

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a solution, but it might be a workaround:

1. In a GitHub PR, change the tab from "Conversation" to "Files changed".
2. Open the dropdown called "Conversations" which lists all of them. Unresolved conversations are listed first.

[image: GitHub PR Conversations Dropdown Example]

User [ldog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63883807/disable-hidden-conversations-in-github-pull-requests/69135692#comment131937717_69135692) explains some limitations with this in the comments below:

> Unfortunately this only works if the comments are in sync with the latest commit or the commits that you are currently looking at, if you wanted to see all comments across all commits, this doesn't work. For example, when clicking on a comment that no longer exists due to code changes in a commit this does nothing.

I would prefer to find the same solution the OP is seeking, but I wanted to share this for anyone else landing here with the same issue in case someone finds it helpful.

Also, I'm cross-posting this information in [a related webapps.stackexchange question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/148308/how-to-always-show-all-pr-conversations-in-github).

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if the comments are in sync with the latest commit or the commits that you are currently looking at, if you wanted to see all comments across all commits, this doesn't work. For example, when clicking on a comment that no longer exists due to code changes in a commit this does nothing. Thanks for the partial solution though.

Comment: @ldog can you re-check? I tried switching between commits, and when I checked the dropdown, it always lists all conversations regardless of chosen commit. It also reloads the page with the changes containing the conversation when one is chosen. Maybe you mean it is in sync with the full set of changes in the PR (not the latest commit or any particular commit). More testing will be needed to confirm.